# How can I prove that the suspension of a Moore space of type $(G, n-1)$ is a Moore space of type $(G,n)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I am reading this paper of MARTIN ARKOWITZ AND MAREK GOLASINSKI:

> [image]

Specifically, I am reading section 1, which is the introduction. In it, the authors said: "It is well known that Moore spaces exist and that any two of type $(G,n)$ have the same homotopy type."Also, the authors added (at the beginning of section 3): "Every Moore space $M(G,n), n \geq 3$ is a suspension."

**My questions are:**

1- Why any two Moore spaces of type $(G,n)$ have the same homotopy type?

2- How can I prove that: Every Moore space $M(G,n), n \geq 3$ is a suspension?

Could anyone help me in answering those questions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, for $n\geq 2$, a Moore space $M(G,n)$ is a simply connected space (with the homotopy type of a CW complex) whose only nontrivial reduced homology group is $H_n(M(G,n))\cong G$.  From this definition, it is immediate that the suspension of an $M(G,n)$ is an $M(G,n+1)$: the suspension of any path-connected space is simply connected, and the suspension will have the correct homology since suspension raises the dimension of homology by $1$.  (In fact, $M(G,2)$ is also a suspension, namely the suspension of any space whose only nontrivial reduced homology group is $G$ in degree $1$.)

The uniqueness of Moore spaces up to homotopy is harder.  As a sketch of a proof, you can construct a specific $M(G,n)$ by taking a presentation of the abelian group $G$, and then taking a wedge of copies of $S^n$ for each generator and then attaching $(n+1)$-cells for each relation.  Call this space $X$.  For any other $M(G,n)$ space $Y$, there is then a map $f:X\to Y$ which is an isomorphism on homology, and hence a homotopy equivalence by the Whitehead theorem.  To construct this map, notice first that $H_n(Y)\cong \pi_n(Y)$ by Hurewicz.  So, each class in $H_n(Y)$ is represented by a map from $S^n$, so you can map each of the $S^n$s in $X$ to $Y$ so that their classes in $H_n(X)$ will map to the corresponding classes in $H_n(Y)$ (since $H_n(X)\cong H_n(Y)\cong G$).  We can then extend this map over the $(n+1)$-cells we attached to get $X$ since each of those $(n+1)$-cells was attached along relations that map to $0$ in $H_n(Y)\cong \pi_n(Y)$.

Comment: Why we construct the Moore space like that? is this the only way of constructing spaces?

Comment: A quick question, does the OP question implies that every Moore space is a suspension?  if so, why?